# Jmeter: Capturing of tokens (Say 50 tokens) from single request and pass one token at a time to the next upcoming 50 requests

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

we have certain token mechanism recently implemented into our project. What it does is, say it generates 50 tokens while triggering the corresponding  API. Now we have to capture this tokens and pass it sequentially one by one to the next 50 API’s request body. One way is by writing multiple json path extractors I have to capture this values individually and pass it to all the requests. But readability is not proper this way. Is there any other way to capture this tokens and pass it to all the next requests one each. Say capturing those into a file and passing it sequentially or something.

Sample Response from where tokens generated:

```
{
  
  "data" : {
    "requestTokens" : [ "9FDE794DD00E4A09122343BDCAF214E9", "616C5DFFC1234516A925824AEA6EFE9F", "7A8C507EC1DF4AD88E0912345E1DB409", "763C32CF67899946B6BC946949BD1344", "3C143F2FC25E495012345500E0F343DF", "3FD78335C763420B1234574061D9417F", "C43C368A1E612345AB17D2BA2693BEAF", "56E8FA9036D3486123451DE3237004DC", "5867B8E399FB4E12345626337D0E143C", "D06B30BDEAFC4A7D8618BF67712345DB", "F795258D390D4812345EB62C83BEFC58", "F0829D861234560392DE432E121B3CD4", "C8B9D5E6BE6A465FB91B0123459FBA9A", "4169D93D97204123457BA5A98C914D27", "784809E5BCBF4F123459D7D848AD67CE", "D0BFDCDC13994C0123455B2B110C35F9", "4F59619BBEDE4FE812345EA14C5E785", "E3942AE182214605BE91234595D95C18", "2005C506659C425EAD2022446123459B", "FE716E2A13A74C759C12345AED5AD54C" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) as a child of the request which returns this JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. Add [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) after the request which returns this JSON
4. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
5. Put your "next request" as a child of the ForEach Controller
6. Refer the token as `${token}` in this request
7. That's it, ForEach Controller will loop as many times as there are tokens in the first response and each iteration the `${token}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) will be updated with the new value

Demo:

[image]